# how do i restrict pages in ionic and firebase-authentication

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

As far as I can tell what I'm after is pretty basic, but I can't seem to find a clear solution to it, at least in the way I've built it up so far. I'm now completely stumped.

I've got the firebase email/password login working perfectly and redirecting to a registrants page. However I obviously want some safeguard in the registrants page to say 'If I'm not logged in, go back to the login page'.

In my `authentication-service.ts` I've set up a property of the class `authService` called `isLoggedIn` that just returns a true/false:

```
get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    console.log('user: ' + user);
    return (user !== null ) ? true : false;
  }
```

So I presumed (wrongly) that I could put the following in the `ngOnInit()` in the registrants page after the user is logged in, just so it'll fire up a check if the user is logged in once the page is visited, I can enter the `redirectByUrl` once I know it's working:

```
console.log('loggedin: ' + this.authService.isLoggedIn);
```

But I've learned that `ngOnInit` is only ever called once. So you could go into the page, then logout, then go back and it won't check if the user is logged in.

It works when i refresh the page, but not when it visits it within links. Is there a certain lifecycle hook that will check every time someone clicks on the link to visit the page or is it done a much simpler way?

I've realised I can put it in a `ngDoCheck()` but that seems a little excessive doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `ionViewWillEnter`?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle